# Cannot find local copy of Postgres installation with Maven

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, maven

I added the following dependency to my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
     <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
     <version>9.4-1206-jdbc42</version>
</dependency>
```

and ran `mvn install`. I'm trying to start a local Postgres database like so:

```
$ psql
$ createdb -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres springbootdb password *********
```

according to [this](https://dzone.com/articles/configuring-spring-boot-for-postgresql) tutorial, but i cannot find the `bin/` folder of my local maven repository's postgres installation. In fact, I cannot find the local Postgres package at all. I'm looking in the `~/.m2/repository` directory. What am I doing wrong?

Note: I'm using version 3.0.5 of Maven on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Where are you running that ? Is that all of starting script? Looks like invalid.... whats createdb??

Comment: have you installed postgres on your ubuntu machine ? or you have just ran mvn install ?

Comment: @FahadAnjum I've installed postgres on my machine

Comment: @Antoniossss `createdb` is run on the psql server itself. I shouldve clarified that. Please see updated question.

Comment: You probably can't find it because maven didn't install it. Are you sure maven is supposed to install it? I think it only installs de postgresql-jdbc driver. You can install postgres on ubuntu with `sudo apt-get install postgresql`.

Comment: Installing a jdbc driver isn't the same as installing postgres. You need first to install postgres and you need the jdbc driver to connect to the installed postgres from java.

Comment: @dopatraman postgresql-jdbc is just a driver - library that allows to connecto to running database, not the database itself